# How to make a route synchronous

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I have a route to comments where i want to fetch all comments for a particular docket no. Again for every comment there may be multiple files. i Want to fetch them all in a synchronous way, whereas with nodeJS by default its work in a asynchronous way. Both comments and files are stored in different collections.

This is the route where I want to return the result as a single JS object

```
router.get("/history/:docket_no", (req, res) => {
    Comments.find({ docket_no: req.params.docket_no })
    .exec()
    .then(comments => {
        var cmnts = [];
        if (comments.length >= 1) {
            for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
                var cmntImgs = [];
                CommentImage.find({ comment_id: comments[i]._id })
                .exec()
                .then(commentImages => {
                    for(var j = 0; j < commentImages.length; j++) {
                        var filePath = commentImages[j].comment_image;
                        var fileName = filePath.split("\\");
                        cmntImgs[j] = {
                            filesName: fileName[fileName.length-1],
                            filePath: filePath
                        };
                    }
                    console.log('Images',cmntImgs);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                });

                cmnts[i] = {
                    id: comments[i]._id,
                    user_name: comments[i].user_name,
                    role_id: comments[i].role_id,
                    message: comments[i].message,
                    create_date: comments[i].create_date,
                    files: cmntImgs
                };
            };

            return res.status(200).json({
                comments: cmnts
            });

        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({
                msg: "No comments found"
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.send(500).json({
          msg: "Error"
        });
    });
});
```

This is the Comment Schema...

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Comments Schema
const CommentsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    docket_no: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    role_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    create_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comments", CommentsSchema);
```

This is the Files Schema...

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//CommentImage Schema
const CommentImage = mongoose.Schema({
    docket_no: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    comment_id: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    comment_image: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("CommentImage", CommentImage);
```

This is the current output-

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": "5c3efdf77ad5e5176cc65bc4",
            "user_name": "aaa",
            "role_id": 1,
            "message": "comment test 1",
            "create_date": "2019-01-16T09:48:39.023Z",
            "files": []
        },
        {
            "id": "5c40311bdad6ad1084d24b9c",
            "user_name": "aaa",
            "role_id": 1,
            "message": "comment test 1",
            "create_date": "2019-01-17T07:39:07.081Z",
            "files": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired Output-

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": "5c3efdf77ad5e5176cc65bc4",
            "user_name": "aaa",
            "role_id": 1,
            "message": "comment test 1",
            "create_date": "2019-01-16T09:48:39.023Z",
            "files": []
        },
        {
            "id": "5c40311bdad6ad1084d24b9c",
            "user_name": "aaa",
            "role_id": 1,
            "message": "comment test 1",
            "create_date": "2019-01-17T07:39:07.081Z",
            "files": [
                        {
                            filesName: '1547710746976-FD Direct Screen #2.jpg',
                            filePath: 'uploads\\1547710746976-FD Direct Screen #2.jpg' },
                        {
                            filesName: '1547710746987-New Doc 2018-05-31.doc',
                            filePath: 'uploads\\1547710746987-New Doc 2018-05-31.doc' },
                        {
                            filesName: '1547710747024-New Doc 2018-05-31.docx',
                            filePath: 'uploads\\1547710747024-New Doc 2018-05-31.docx' },
                        {
                            filesName: '1547710747053-New Doc 2018-05-31.pdf',
                            filePath: 'uploads\\1547710747053-New Doc 2018-05-31.pdf' }
                    ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: also see [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose does not support synchronous operations. You will need to turn your route handler into an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function in order to take advantage of `await`. This makes it seem/read like it's synchronous.

Error handling should be delegated to Express' [error middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

```
router.get("/history/:docket_no", async (req, res) => {
    const { docket_no } = req.params
    const comments = await Comments.find({ docket_no }).exec()

    if (comments.length < 1) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: "No comments found."})
        return
    }

    const mappedComments = []
    const mappedImages = []

    for(let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        const images = await CommentImages
            .find({ comment_id: comments[i]._id })
            .exec()

        for(let j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
            const filePath = images[j].comment_image
            const fileName = filePath.split("\\")
            mappedImages[j] = {
                filesName: fileName[fileName.length - 1],
                filePath
            }
        }

        console.log(`Images ${mappedImages}`)

        const {
            _id,
            user_name,
            role_id,
            message,
            create_date
        } = comments[i]

        mappedComments[i] = {
            id: _id,
            user_name,
            role_id,
            message,
            create_date,
            files: mappedImages
        }
    }

    res.json({ comments: mappedComments })
})
```

The above example also takes advantage of [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: This serializes the database access (i.e. it's slower than it needs to be). async/await is nice, but it's not a good thing to use in a loop.

Comment: Thanks this what I was looking for. This thing worked for me. But you removed the then and catch block completely. Is there any way to do it in the then and catch block.

Comment: Yes the response is slow in my case as there is 2 loops working.

Comment: @Tomalak there's no difference in performance between promises and async/await with the same implementation

Comment: There is, when you do `async`/`await` in a `for` loop.

Comment: @Xvistasss No, `catch and `then` are functions a `Promise` object. You asked for a _synchronous_ way which using `async-await` gives you that "synchronous" feel you were after.

Comment: Thanks buddy @FranciscoMateo